# How to send data from a text box from one form to the other in angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, forms

I am using this sample form to send data. I currently watch under the console. But I really need to send these information to another page called result.html and I want to know how to do that. Currently I am using the following code in the main page... Here is the code

```html
<!-- File: chapter4/two-forms-databinding.html -->
<html ng-app="notesApp">
<head><title>Notes App</title></head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">

  <form ng-submit="ctrl.submit1()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.username">
    <input type="password" ng-model="ctrl.password">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

  <form ng-submit="ctrl.submit2()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.user.username">
    <input type="password" ng-model="ctrl.user.password">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

<script
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  angular.module('notesApp', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', [function() {
      var self = this;
      self.submit1 = function() {
        // Create user object to send to the server
        var user = {username: self.username, password: self.password};
        console.log('First form submit with ', user);
      };
      self.submit2 = function() {
        console.log('Second form submit with ', self.user);
      };
    }]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to know how should be the code in the result.html page to grab the parameters sent by these forms. Please help me I am really new to angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!-- File: chapter4/two-forms-databinding.html -->
<html ng-app="notesApp">
<head><title>Notes App</title></head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">

  <form ng-submit="ctrl.submit1()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.username">
    <input type="password" ng-model="ctrl.password">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

  <form ng-submit="ctrl.submit2()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.user.username">
    <input type="password" ng-model="ctrl.user.password">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

<script
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  angular.module('notesApp', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', [function() {
      var self = this;
      self.submit1 = function() {
        // Create user object to send to the server
        self.user = {username: self.username, password: self.password};
        console.log('First form submit with ', self.user);
      };
      self.submit2 = function() {
        console.log('Second form submit with ', self.user);
      };
    }]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is the modified code which is populating data to the second form on submit of first form check by running